# How do I change the desktop wallpaper on my Pi. I am using Jessie.

Tags: troubleshooting

I have a number of images shown for my wallpaper in preferences but whatever I click on, does not change the wallpaper.

I want to go back to the Raspberry Pi image and when I click on that image nothing changes.

If these pictures are corrupt, I have a jpeg of the pi image but I do not know how to load it.  I would try this if there is no solution to the existing images but don't know how to do that.  Sorry for being long winded.  I am a newbie!  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

So here is the solution for Raspbian Stretch

pcmanfm --set-wallpaper yourfile.jpg

The file can be on any path that is available to read by the user. Here I have assumed it to be /home/pi.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on Buster, so Jessie may be a bit different.

Pcmanfm sets its wallpaper based on what the config file tells it to.
The config file is located at `/home/pi/.config/pcmanfm/LXDE-pi/desktop-items-0.conf`.

Simply change the `wallpaper=` line to the full path of the image you want.

Answer (score 0):

You change the Picture in `Preferences/Appearance Settings/Desktop/Pictures`

I use `/usr/share/raspberrypi-artwork/raspberry-pi-logo-small.png`.

I Am not sure if `jpeg` works, most use `png`

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have tried going to the location you suggested.  I have the png logo listed as an option but selecting it does not change the wallpaper.  I tried going back to the defaults and it lists a different wallpaper but it still does not change from the existing wallpaper.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I will try it the next time I log in and let you know if it works.  Thanks again.